# Why brass knuckles do 0 additional damage in Vampire: The Requiem 2nd Edition?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-2e, vampire-the-requiem-2e

I've been creating a character and thought that it was cool for her to have brass knuckles to fight, but then I've seen that in the Core book (pg. 180) says that brass knuckles deal 0 damage (appart from the damage that you deal with raw brawl. In the Chronicles of Darkness 2nd Edition core book says the same.

Is this an errata, or there's something I'm missing?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Brass knuckles deal lethal damage, while unarmed attacks deal bashing damage by default.

Vampire the Requiem 2e p181

> Fists and feet, along  with  other  kinds  of  low-impact  trauma,
> deal  bashing damage.  Brass  knuckles,  knives,  and  speeding  trucks
> deal  lethal damage.